# How to filter an Outlook view in VBA based on "To" email addresses

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I have a view in Outlook that includes both "From" and "To" emails from a mailbox

I can very easily type in an email address into the Outlook search box, and the view will be instantly filtered to show all emails to and from the email address (plus perhaps, any other emails including this email address in the subject or body, but that's not an issue)

I would like to replicate this process via VBA - I have an Access DB with contact details, and would like to be able to simply filter this view based on a contact email address in the DB.

It seems like a very simple problem, but I can't find the solution. I have code that eg filters based on the from email address, but there seems no way to filter on a 'To' email address (I can filter on the 'To' display name but this is next to useless - it varies from one email to another, and seldom if ever contains the actual email address)

I have a DASL filter code that works to filter on the 'From' email addresses using DASL syntax as follows:

```
Const SchemaFrom As String = "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail"
Dim EM as string
EM = "myemail@me.com"
objView.Filter = Chr(34) & SchemaFrom & Chr(34) & " = '" & EM & "'"
```

But there is nothing similar for 'To' emails.

Ultimately I don't even need to filter based on eg the 'From' and 'To' email addresses - if there is a way to code this, so, like in the search box, it simply filters on any text field containing the email address that would be fine by me!!!

For example, is there a generic DASL search that will do this, so no need to eg dictate searching in eg fromemail?

All help much appreciated - it is so simple to do in the GUI of Outlook it must be possible from VBA surely?!

Comment: why are you using DASL ?

Comment: @RonanVico: I'm using DASL, as, according to Microsoft docs, the string filter for View.Filter in VBA is DASL:
 "The value of this property is a string, in DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax"

Happy to use any other appropriate method you can advise if it will work!

Comment: As an addendum, I have found a VERY weird issue with DASL for this.

You can use the Outlook filter dialog box to create the DASL for you. But it works oddly,

For example, I can put in an email address on the "Sent To" field in the dialog box, and then pressing OK this works exactly as I need (showing ALL emails sent to this email address, not just those where the email address is in the 'DisaplayTo' name. Great!!

This generates the following DASL code:

Comment: `("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0e04001f" CI_STARTSWITH 'mymail@gmail.com' OR "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0e03001f" CI_STARTSWITH 'mymail@gmail.com')
`

BUT, when you use this code in VBA, the filter only shows emails with the email address in the 'DisaplayTo' field, not all emails as before

ie I get 2 different results, one from the dialog box, one in code, with supposedly the same DASL quesry!!!

Answer (score 0):

*Should be*

```
Dim Filter As String
    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" & _
                       Chr(34) & " Like '%0m3r 0m3r%'"
```

*Or use*

```
Filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = '0m3r@email.com'"
```

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Examples()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim msg As String

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" & _
                           Chr(34) & " Like '%0m3r 0m3r%'"

    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    msg = Items.Count & " Items in " & Inbox.Name

    MsgBox (msg)
    
End Sub
```

***[MSDN fromemail Field | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2003/aa123730%28v%3Dexchg.65%29)***

---

***Edit***

*for to. try*

> `urn:schemas:httpmail:to`
> Or
> `urn:schemas:mailheader:to`

Comment: In fact, for the View.Filter DASL there's no need to add the "@SQL=" (see the example here on Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.filter)

As I noted, the code as posted works fine, I am trying to find the equivalent for the 'To' email address (NB and it HAS to be the email address NOT the display name)

FYI I am also not looking to return a collection I can inspect etc - I want the results returned in the Outlook window so the user sees the filtered emails.

Any help you can provide much appreciated!