# Searching olFolderSentMail by domain of email address with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to find mail in the olFolderSentMail folder, using the domains of the email addresses, with VBA.

When I make an advanced filter in Outlook, the result comes. I got the sql code from there. There is no result in VBA.

For example, I want to find a@kpmg.com, b@kpmg.com both together. Only names appear in the whom section in Outlook as a and b. Mail addresses are hidden in names.

```vb
Sub sentmails()
 
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI") Dim
olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

filterstr = "@SQL=(""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0e04001f""
CI_STARTSWITH 'kpmg' OR ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0e03001f"" CI_STARTSWITH 'kpmg')"

Set arama = olFolder.Items.Restrict(filterstr)

End Sub
```

Comment: The question cannot be easily understood which is possibly why there was a downvote. It appears to be about the known issue of SQL success vs VBA fail. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924883/how-to-filter-an-outlook-view-in-vba-based-on-to-email-addresses and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413285/search-by-email-address-for-latest-email-in-all-folders-and-reply-all

Comment: When I search outlook, the result comes out, I use the sql query in outlook in vba, the result is not coming.

Comment: Appears I understood the question. The links appear to agree, in this case, the incorrect result is expected with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are not searching for a suffix (`*kpmg.com`), you are searching for a prefix (`kpmg*`).
Secondly, `To`/`CC`/`BCC` properties might not even contain email addresses, only names.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), one can create a subrestriction on the message recipients, but Outlook Object Model does not expose it.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use a script similar to the one below:

```
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
Set folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
set restItems = folder.Items.Restrict("Recipients LIKE '%kpmg.com%' ")
MsgBox restItems.Count
```

Comment: thank you dmitry. I'll try your advice and share the situation here.

Comment: Can't the solution be developed without redemption installation?

Comment: Do you mean without Redemption? Or using Redemption without an installer? In the latter case, the installation is simply copying the dll to any folder and registering it using regsvr32,exe

Comment: Can you send the dll file to me. Isn't there a solution without redemption?

Comment: You can create a restriction in Extended MAPI, but you can only do that in C++ or Delphi, VB won't let you use Extended MAPI.
Redemption can be downloaded from http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for your support. It was very useful. 
Can I get folders in olfolderinbox in a single query.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean you need to lop through the subfolders? Use MAPIFolder.Folders collection.

Comment: If you know the folder name, you can just use it instead of an integer index: `set subFolder = ParentFolder.Folders("The Name")`