# Why (Outlook vba api) AdvancedSearch returns the wrong email result when searching email sent to someone?

Tags: vba, outlook, autohotkey, outlook-restapi

Hello all and thank you for your support,

Please, anyone knows how to get both cases where email is "something@emailprovider.com" and "Name Surname"?

I'm using the following filter

```
; email Search Parameters
lookForRecipient            := ReceiverEmail
strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto like '%" lookForRecipient "%'"
emailScopeFolder            := "\\myemail@outlook.com\inbox\myFolder\mysubFolder"
searchSubfolders            := True
searchObject := this.outlook.AdvancedSearch(emailScopeFolder, strQuery, searchSubfolders)

; Wait until Outlook's AdvancedSearch returns AdvancedSearchComplete
oSearchEvents           := new SearchEvents
ComObjConnect(this.outlook, oSearchEvents)
    while (!oSearchEvents.SearchComplete) {
        ToolTip, % "Wait. Search in progress"
    }   

; Get final results. Sort the results by time received time, selecting the newest (latest) one
searchResults := searchObject.Results
countResults := searchResults.Count()
searchResults.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true)
latestSentEmail := searchResults.GetFirst()
```

Obs, elsewhere in the code, I have the class SearchEVents defined

```
class SearchEvents
{
    AdvancedSearchComplete(searchObject)
    {
        ToolTip, % "Wait. SearchEvents.AdvancedSearchComplete() is in progress"
        Sleep, 200
        this.SearchComplete := true
    }
}
```

And it works to find latest email sent.
But not always.

If the email "ReceiverEmail" is something like "abc@hotmail.com"

This would be found
[image]

But this would not be found
[image]

So, using displayTo as namespace, it finds the email only if the email really appears in the To Field. If instead of the email there is a "name", the email is not found!

How can I search in "To" field?

Obs: I tried the options below without success.

[image]

Or, in text format,

```
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; WORKS, but only if ToField is something@emailprovider.com
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:namespace:to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:reply-to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:reply_to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:reply_by like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:httpmail:reply-by like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; error

;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:mailheader:to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:mailheader:in-reply-to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
;strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:mailheader:reply-to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result

strQuery                    := "urn:schemas:mailheader:return-receipt-to like '%" lookForRecipient "%'" ; no result
```

Please, anyone knows how to get both cases where email is "something@emailprovider.com" and "Name Surname"?

Thank you very much!

===============================
@niton

I have tried Items.Restrict(strFiler) as the link you sent without success.

```
subboxMail                  := 

this.mailBox.Folders(this.emailBox).Folders(this.emailSubBox)
    
strFilter                   := "@SQL=" Chr(34) "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0076001E" Chr(34) " like '%" lookForRecipient "%'"



restrictResults             := subboxMailItems.Restrict(strFilter)
                restrictResultsCount        := restrictResults.Count

                msgbox, % "searchedSubFolderCount = " searchedSubFolderCount "`n`n strFilter = " strFilter "`n`n restrictResultsCount = " restrictResultsCount
```

The message box returns
searchSubfolderCount = 2000+ (the exact number of emails in the folder)
but
restrictResultCount = 0

[image]

Obs, and if I use two times the double quotes (") it raises an error.
[image]

Comment: Address-related searches are problematic. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64217427/1571407. "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" appears to be misunderstood or incorrectly implemented. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413285/search-by-email-address-for-latest-email-in-all-folders-and-reply-all#comment112132153_63413285

Comment: Niton, thanks for your reply. Tried your link (Items.Restrict(strFilter)) without success and added comment in the original post.

Comment: I am suggesting query implementation **may** not be  correct in **VBA**. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924883/how-to-filter-an-outlook-view-in-vba-based-on-to-email-addresses. In a comment  "...I get 2 different results, one from the dialog box, one in code, with supposedly the same DASL quesry!"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same problem... Thanks, Niton!

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve AccountName from email? This way, we could search for displayTo = AccountName first retrieving AccountName from email...

Comment: If you cannot find a previously asked question create one. Leave this one open in case there is a solution.

Comment: @niton I got it working("kind of") using a workaround.
As I was not finding a solution, I found a workaround: write in tiny (on invisible color, same as background) letters "emailSentTo:xxx@yyy.com" at the body of the email. Then, use AdvancedSearch with argument "urn:schemas:httpmail:textDescription" like %emailSentTo:xxx@yyy.com".